# Picture taken on portrait mode is saved rotated counter clockwise?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm building a camera app, I'm requesting the camera instance this way and the preview is shown in the right angle:

```
        c = Camera.open();
        c.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

However after the user takes a photo and loading it into an imageView it's rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise. This is how I save the photo:

```
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        try {
            String filePath = folderPath + generateFileName();
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream( filePath );
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            // Put into imageView
            File file = new  File(filePath);
            if(file.exists()){
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                last_photo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

How can I save the image without it being rotated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `setRotation()` instead, or in addition to, `setDisplayOrientation()`. That method is described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29)

Comment: Note that `setRotation()` may only choose to play with the EXIF flags. The result is an image which is still rotated 90°, but with a "flag" that describes the correct orientation. Not all viewers correctly account for this flag. Specifically, `BitmapFactory` ignores it. You can draw the bitmap rotated on a canvas, or rotate the bitmap acquired from `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`, or manipulate the JPEG data before writing it into `outStream` using a third party lib.